# How to pass selected value to javascript function from radio button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, controller, radio-button

I have three radio buttons which all have hidden `<div>`'s under each of them (this radio button works if I didn't bind them to the model). If you click `<div>` one and decided to click a second radio button, it will hide the first one and this also applies to the other one.

However, each radio button has its own functionality which it will perform. So on the controller I have an If-statement for each radio button. After I have bound each radio button to the model, they no longer work and they don't get de-selected when I select another radio button and no longer hide `<div>`'s.
I am not sure if there's something I am missing. Thanks.

```
    Razor Code

     <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 165px;">    
        <div class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Isrd1, "one",true, new { id = "id1" }) Radio One
        </div>

        <div class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Isrd2, "two", new { id = "id2" })Radio two
        </div>

         <div class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Isrd3, "three", new { id = "id3" })Radio three
        </div>
    </div>
```

My model:

```
    public class ModelSelection
    { 
         public string Types { get; set; }

         public string Isrd1 { get; set; }
         public string Isrd2 { get; set; }
         public string Isrd3 { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller:

```
     if (md.Types == "one")
     {
     }

     if (md.Types == "two")
     {
     }

     if (md.Types == "three")
     {
     }
```

My JavaScript:

```
          $('input[name=Isrd1]').click(function () {
                if (this.id == "id1") {
                    $("#div1").show('slow');
                    $("#div2").hide('slow');
                    $("#div3").hide('slow');
                }
            });

             $('input[name=Isrd2]').click(function () {
                if (this.id == "id2") {
                    $("#div2").show('slow');
                    $("#div1").hide('slow');
                    $("#div3").hide('slow');

               $('input[name=Isrd3]').click(function () {
                if (this.id == "id3") {
                    $("#div3").show('slow');
                    $("#div1").hide('slow');
                    $("#div2").hide('slow');
```

Comment: The purpose of radio buttons is to select one from many, and they work by being grouped - i.e. each radio button in a group has the same name attribute. Your buttons all have different `name` attributes so they do not make sense (you can select then all and cannot un-select any)

Comment: @StephenMuecke for them to make sense, can you help me in terms of editing where you think i have made mistake ?

Comment: Based on your `if (md.Types == "one") { ....` code, then your radio buttons need to be `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Types , "one", new { id = "" })<span>Radio One</span></label>` (and ditto for `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Types , "one", new { id = "" })` etc) - In the POST method, the value of `Types` will be the value of the selected button ("one", "two", or "three"). Your `Isrd1`, `Isrd2` and `Isrd3`properties are not required for your radio buttons

Comment: You also need to change you script - should be `$('input[name="Types"]').change(function() { ... });` but I do not know what your divs with `id="div1" etc are in the DOM and how thy relate to the radio buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Radio button works mutually exclusively when they are having same name, so make sure you are having final generated HTML of radios with same name, then only when you select one radio, another will get deselect.

final HTML be Like

```
<div class="radio-inline">
    <input id="id1" name="radio" value="1" /> <label>radio 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline">
    <input id="id2" name="radio" value="2" /><label>radio 2</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline">
    <input id="id3" name="radio" value="3" /><label>radio 3</label>
</div>
```

The models you defined can then be handled using either class selector or on basis of id.

Either you should have code your radio button like

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Isrd, "one",true, new { id = "id1" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Irsd,"two", true, new {id = "id2"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Irsd,"three", true, new {id = "id3"})
```

this way your radio button will work the way they should work, i.e. mutually exclusive

Comment: I am using Razor and also binding each radio button to a model.

Comment: check how html of input is looking in developer tool, and their names.

Comment: also for binding, try to use id or class as selectors for radios.

Comment: Radio button doesn't take four arguments.

Comment: You yourself has passed four arguments. Also Please check `http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-radiobutton-radiobuttonfor` link